# Django ORM: time zone support

Tags: django, django-models, timezone

Can you recommend any implementation of Time Zones support for Django's ORM (DateTime filed)?

Ideally it has to be DB-agnostic and transparent, allowing to use all standard ORM things like __lt, __gt etc.

I guess it needs to store time in UTC plus local timezone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UTCDateTime](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/388/) seems to satisfy most of the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [django-timezones app](http://code.google.com/p/django-timezones/).  It was posted in response to [ticket #8953](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8953) on the django bug tracker.  The ticket also talks about a [bulbs application](https://code.launchpad.net/~theonion/bulbs/trunk) that the Onion uses on their site to handle timestamps.

Comment: Unfortunately, "**Please note:** Bulbs is deprecated and no longer maintained." http://github.com/korpios/bulbs/tree/master

Comment: Thought Bulbs is unmaintained it remains the same as the code used internally at the Onion for timezone support (I was an intern there over the summer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a pre-canned implementation you can use, but [this post](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/08/fuzzydates-or-one-django-model-field-multiple-database-columns/) discusses how to implement a Django date field which maps to multiple database columns.